# Netbeans Code Complete not activating when looping through array of objects

Tags: php, netbeans, object

In my Netbeans PHP projects, I recently started stuffing custom objects into arrays in order to increase performance.  I found its [much faster](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html) to query the database and get a bunch of objects all at once instead of querying over and over again.

I love the new approach, except when I loop through the array and try to access each of the objects, Netbeans doesn't know that the items in the array are actually objects.  Try to following example code, for instance:

```
    foreach ($arrAccounts as $objAccount) {
         echo ( $objAccount->get_name() . " - " . $objAccount->get_type() );
         ...

    }
```

When I type "$objAccount->", Netbeans doesn't recognize that it is a custom Account class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside the loop add vdoc and enter classname of the `$objAccount`

Shortcut = [vdoc + tab]

```
foreach ($arrAccounts as $objAccount) {
    /* @var $objAccount ClassName */
    ...
}
```

Comment: never really bothered to look this up, but sure am glad to know now!

Comment: that is awesome...plain and simple.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be phpdoc for array of elements if you add "[]" after classname:

```
/* @var $arrAccounts ClassName[] */
```

I find this better for code clarity because you specify the type of your array once. Then it does not matter if you assign it within foreach() or you directly access elements of the array directly based on keys.